# UIImageView change

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, ibeacon

This code changes a `UIImageView` I have at the top of a ViewController. The only problem is, when the image changes from one image to another, it just disappears from the screen. I believe it's a sizing issue, can anyone help me fix this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var glyph: UIImageView!

var imageView = UIImageView()

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "Estimotes")

let images = [
    53219:  UIImage(named:"IOKids White Glyph 2"),
    59317:  UIImage(named:"IOKids White Glyph 3"),
    17068: UIImage(named:"IOKids White Glyph 4")
]


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown }
    if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        self.glyph.image = self.images[closestBeacon.minor.intValue]!

        self.glyph.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
}
```

Comment: You code looks okay. Have you tried to use another set of image? Are you sure that the problem happens only on the second image, no matter what set of images you assign to the array?

Comment: comment this line self.glyph.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Comment: There are a few things you can try.. Like, do `let image = self.images[closestBeacon.minor.intValue]!`, then do `print(image.size)` before doing `self.glyph.image = image`. then you can see the image size. You can also try `self.glyph.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor; self.glyph.layer.borderWidth = 1` to see if you can still see the imageView. Or you could try adding `self.glyph.sizeToFit()` after changing the image. Maybe you have added constraints that get confused when changing? Also, why do you have an ImageView named glyph and another named `imageView`. Are you using the right one?